# Standard non-conformance in Visual C++'s <random>

Tags: c++, visual-studio, random, std

The N3337 document defines (among others) functions for generating random numbers, like `std::mt19937` or `std::uniform_int_distribution`.

This is an example of a code that is compileable in Visual Studio:

```cpp
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::mt19937 generator(200);
    const std::discrete_distribution<int> distribution({41, 9, 40, 10});

    for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        char a = 'A' + distribution(generator);
        std::cout << a;
    }

    std::cout << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is the `const` specifier before `std::discrete_distribution`. The N3337 document states that `operator()` of probably all distribution functions is NOT marked with `const`. This means it shouldn't be possible to call `operator()` on a `const` object. Yet Visual Studio doesn't have any problem with it, because in its headers the `operator()` method inside most distribution functions do contain the `const` specifier (it seems the only exception is `std::normal_distribution` -- they don't have `const` there!).

It doesn't help that the MSDN documentation for `std::discrete_distribution` doesn't have the `const` specifier, while in reality the header does have `const`: [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/discrete-distribution-class?view=vs-2017)

Is there a reason for Visual Studio non-conformance with the standard here?

It is a problem, because it makes code written in Visual Studio not compileable in other compilers, like GCC, which has `operator()` properly marked as `non-const` and doesn't allow the program above to be compiled.

Comment: The standard permits an implementation to provide extensions, so long as the meaning of a well-formed standard program is not altered. This is one such instance.

Comment: Is there any reason the distribution should change over time ?

Comment: @SidS: Efficiency. Simple case: a uniform distribution over [0,16) only needs to consume 4 bits of randomness per output, which means it doesn't need to call the generator for every output.

Comment: It is never very obvious how this happened.  PJ Plauger's first version of the random header was pretty buggy, fixing bugs like this is always troublesome.  The library maintainer is Stephan T. Lavavej (aka STL), he invites anybody to send him an email about issues like this.  Send to stl at microsoft.com

Comment: @HansPassant -- in fairness to PJ Plauger, I'm the one who implemented the random number library for Dinkumware.